# Reference request: $|\partial_t u - \Delta u|\in L^p(\Omega^T)$ implies Holder estimate

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, parabolic-pde

I am currently reading a paper regarding harmonic flow between Riemannian manifolds. Let $\Omega$ be a Riemannian domain of dimension $2$, $\Omega^T=\Omega\times[0,T]$. The equation is 
$$
\partial_t u - \Delta u = f
$$

A certain part of the paper claims that

> If we have $f\in L^p(\Omega^T)$ for all $p<\infty$, where
>   $$
> ||f||_{L^p(\Omega^T)} \le C(p,E),
> $$
>   then it is possible to obtained Holder estimate for $u$ in terms of $E$.

The paper says that this follows from a theorem in *Linear and quasilinear equations of parabolic type* by Ladyzenkaya. However, the notations used in the book are extremely hard to read. I cannot even understand the statement of the theorem.

I have a feeling that this might be a relatively standard result. Could anyone guide me to a more modern reference to such result? Perhaps a textbook on parabolic PDE that deals with this would be perfect.

**Edit**: There are probably some information I didn't include that could be relevant to this estimate. If you think something is missing or if a similar but weaker statement holds then please do tell. It might be what I actually need.

Comment: What is $E$ here?

Comment: It can surely be found somewhere in "Second Order Parabolic Differential Equations" by Lieberman, but I don't have a copy in front of me to give you a page or section.

Comment: @NateEldredge It's the energy of $u_0$, i.e. $\int_{\Omega} |\nabla u_0|^2$.